# Singleton in scope of a request in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, singleton

Using singleton mixin from rails I could create a singleton class in the scope of rails app. But I was wondering Is there a way to create it in the scope of a particular request ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since a request is tied to a thread, you can use [`Thread` local](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Thread.html) store:

```
class RequestSingleton
  def self.instance
    Thread.current['request-singleton'] ||= RequestSingleton.new
  end

  def self.clear
    Thread.current['request-singleton'] = nil
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
def index
  RequestSingleton.instance.do_some_setup

  # ...

  RequestSingleton.clear
end
```

...and anywhere else simply use `RequestSingleton.instance` to access it.

Since it is thread local, there are no synchronization issues.