# Select badges from table only if all requirements rows exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I got three tables.
I want to query the badges table to get the badge if all the missions exists for the `badge_id` in the `badge_requirements` table.

In the case below, the badge would be returned because for `badge_id = 1`, all missions exist.

But if, for example, one record in the `finished_missions` table would not exist, then no badge would be returned.

The `user_id` will be supplied from the application.

```
table badges
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | image |
+----+------+-------+
| 1  | OHYE | path  |
+----+------+-------+
PK(id)

table badge_requirements
+------------+----------+
| mission_id | badge_id |
+------------+----------+
| 3          | 1        |
+------------+----------+
| 5          | 1        |
+------------+----------+
UNIQUE(mission_id, badge_id)
FK(mission_id, missions.id)
FK(badge_id, badges.id)

table finished_missions
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | mission_id |
+----+---------+------------+
| 3  | 221     | 3          | // if any of these record doesn't exist
+----+---------+------------+
| 5  | 221     | 5          | // the badge associated with this mission would not be returned
+----+---------+------------+
PK(id)
FK(user_id, users.id)
FK(mission_id, missions.id)
```

**EDIT**
Changed the `missions` table to `finished_missions` for better readability.
The user id and mission id are just referencing the user and mission table.

**EDIT 2**
I've tried this, given from an answer:

```
SELECT * FROM badges b
INNER JOIN finished_missions fm ON (fm.user_id = 221)
INNER JOIN badge_requirements br ON (br.mission_id = fm.mission_id AND br.badge_id = b.id)
```

But it still returns the badge even if I have just one record in `finished_missions` table.

Comment: So, what's the expected result (with the specified table data)?

Comment: That would be the full row from the badges table.

Comment: Your tables are not properly defined. For the best answer we'd need to know all constraints, especially NOT NULL, PK, FK and UNIQUE constraints.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What does `user_id` have to do with anything?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: `The user_id will be supplied from the application.` I think it's clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways. This should be one:

```
SELECT badge_id
FROM  (  -- count missions per badge for the given user
   SELECT br.badge_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   finished_missions fm
   JOIN   badge_requirements br USING (mission_id)
   WHERE  fm.user_id = 221
   GROUP  BY  1
   ) u  -- count missions per badge total
JOIN (
   SELECT br.badge_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   badge_requirements
   ) b USING (badge_id, ct)  -- only badges with the full count of missions
```

In addition to the constraints you declared there should also be a, `UNIQUE(user, mission_id)` on `finished_missions` to disallow duplicate entries. Or you have to use `count(DISTINCT mission_id) AS ct` in the first subquery, so you can rely on the count.

And `UNIQUE(mission_id, badge_id)` should really be the PK  - or add a `NOT NULL` constraint for both columns.

Comment: Great answer! I understand that UNIQUE(user, mission_id) is good to have, but why is PK(mission_id, badge_id) needed on the badge_requirements table? I already have a UNIQUE(mission_id, badge_id).

Comment: @Doodlemeat: A PK imposes NOT NULL on all involved columns - UNIQUE does not, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20006502/939860. You wouldn't want an entry in `badge_requirements` with `mission_id IS NULL`. That requirement would be impossible to meet.

Answer (score 1):

One method is a counting method:

```
select br.badge_id
from badge_requirements br
group by br.badge_id
having count(distinct mission_id) = (select count(*) from missions);
```

This returns the `badge_id`.  If you want more information, join back to the `badges` table or use `in`.

And, if there are no duplicates in `badge_requirements`, then use `count(*)` instead of `count(distinct)`.

Comment: It seems like I can't supply the users id in here.

Comment: @Doodlemeat . . . I think you would just add a `where` clause to the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from badges b
inner join mission m on (m.user_id=@userid)
inner join badge_requirements br on (br.mission_id=m.mission_id and br.badge_id=b.id)
```

where @userid is SQL parameter.

Comment: I actually did exactly this query before asking question. The problem was that if just one mission exist, the badge is still returned.

Comment: no way, because badhr is connected to mission_id, and mission to user id if there is no record that badge wont be returned. for user.

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id, badge_id
from
    badge_requirements br on b.id = br.badge_id
    inner join
    missions m on m.id = br.mission_id
group by user_id, badge_id
having
    array_agg(distinct br.mission_id order by br.mission_id) =
    array_agg(distinct m.id order by m.id)
where user_id = 221
```

Comment: Can the user id be supplied here?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it has syntax errors with the FROM ... ON