# does pg_repack work for materialized view

Tags: postgresql, pg-repack

Does pg_repack work for materialized views on postgres v11? I am running into issues installing pg_repack client on my server and hence unable to check myself. As per the documentation it says "pg_repack is a PostgreSQL extension which lets you remove bloat from tables and indexes", so I am assuming it includes materialized views as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE tbt CASCADE;

BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE tbt (
    a int PRIMARY KEY
)
WITH (
    fillfactor = 40,
    autovacuum_enabled = OFF
);
INSERT INTO tbt
SELECT
    g
FROM
    generate_series(1, 2000) g;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW tbtmv AS
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tbt;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbtmv_idx ON tbtmv (a);
COMMIT;
```

then

```
--------do the update.
UPDATE
    tbt
SET
    a = a - 10
WHERE
    a < 100;

REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY tbtmv;
```

---

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    pgstattuple ('tbtmv');
```

return

```
table_len          | 73728
tuple_count        | 2000
tuple_len          | 56000
tuple_percent      | 75.95
dead_tuple_count   | 10
dead_tuple_len     | 280
dead_tuple_percent | 0.38
free_space         | 1116
free_percent       | 1.51
```

---

```
 /usr/local/pgsql15/bin/pg_repack -d test15 --table tbtmv
```

return

```
ERROR: pg_repack failed with error: ERROR:  relation "tbtmv" does not exist
```

Then

```
 /usr/local/pgsql15/bin/pg_repack -d test15 --table tbt
```

then  `SELECT * FROM pgstattuple('tbtmv');`

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]------+------
table_len          | 73728
tuple_count        | 2000
tuple_len          | 56000
tuple_percent      | 75.95
dead_tuple_count   | 0
dead_tuple_len     | 0
dead_tuple_percent | 0
free_space         | 1436
free_percent       | 1.95
```

As you can see dead_tuple_count from 10 to 0. I also tried with delete operation, the result is the same. So does pg_repack work for materialized view? The answer is YES.
Key gotcha is that to make materialized view bloat, you need to use:

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED view CONCURRENTLY
```

Comment: Thanks @jian your example shows pg_repack of base table, I want to know if pg_repack can be done on mview.

Comment: @nmakb I updated my answer. before repack and after repack, the oid is the same. nothing change, only when you refresh the materialized view.

Comment: my question is can we run pg_repack on an mview? if an mview gets refresh multiple times, it would have bloat. And instead of running vacuum full on mview, can I run pg_repack on the mview?

Comment: nice question. I will update later. I found a related post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421411/refreshing-materialized-view-concurrently-causes-table-bloat @nmakb