# Perform group by on jsonb object using a json path

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, grafana, jsonb

I have a jsonb object in Postgres column named metrics with following structure:

> {"http": {"GET": {"statusCode": {"200": {"count": 100}, "500": {"count": 322}}}}}

I want to get total count by different *httpmethod*, *statusCode*  so that I can plot it using Grafana. Can someone point me how can I use group by. Expected result should be:

```
httpMethod statusCode sum(count)
GET        200        100
GET        500        322
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the structure is constant, and counts are integer values:

```sql
SELECT h.key AS http_method
     , s.key AS status_code
     , sum((s.value->>'count')::int) AS sum_count
FROM   tbl t
     , jsonb_each(t.js->'http') h
     , jsonb_each(h.value->'statusCode') s
GROUP  BY h.key, s.key;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6ca7ee7aa6564e11704cf83c05c96ca8)*

[`jsonb_each()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) in an implicit `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` join is the key ingredient.

About `LATERAL`:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [Optimizing GROUP BY + COUNT DISTINCT on unnested jsonb column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63038210/optimizing-group-by-count-distinct-on-unnested-jsonb-column/63038532#63038532)

Comment: @Erwin.Thanks very much. It works like a charm although now I am struggling a bit to get this into grafana but that's different battle to fight.