# Unexpected behavior for count on empty table

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, cross-join

I have two tables `table_a` and `table_b` in a PostgreSQL 13 database, having UUIDs primary key columns.

`table_a` has multiple entries, whereas `table_b` is empty (no entry).
The following query returns the expected result, namely `entry_count_a` larger than `0`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ta.uuid) AS entry_count_a FROM table_a ta
```

However, the following query returns `0` for both entry_counts:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ta.uuid) AS entry_count_a, COUNT(DISTINCT tb.uuid) AS entry_count_b FROM table_a ta, table_b tb
```

What is the correct way to write the query, so that `entry_count_a` contains the correct (expected) value > `0`, whereas `entry_count_b` is `0`?

Bonus question: Why does Postgres behave this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query is equivalent to the following one:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ta.uuid) AS entry_count_a, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT tb.uuid) AS entry_count_b 
FROM       table_a ta
CROSS JOIN table_b tb
```

When you apply the cartesian product between two tables, you multiply their cardinality. You get no rows because one of the two tables has cardinality 0, hence 0*n, for any n, is always 0.

If you want to display the two counts correctly, you could use two subqueries as follows:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uuid) FROM table_a) AS entry_count_a,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uuid) FROM table_b) AS entry_count_b
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7rfkmeQgX8rLKGNgxthABq/2).

Comment: [Using only column aliases](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7rfkmeQgX8rLKGNgxthABq/2) might be cleaner

Comment: Cleaner, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Your query will produce the cartesian product table a x table b, because you didn't established the way you want to relate them. Normally, we use WHERE conditions or JOIN clauses. So if you have n lines in A x 0 lines in B, you will get 0 rows as result with your SQL statement.
The easiest way in this case is running two separate querys, one for each table, or using subselects like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ta.uuid) AS entry_count_a, SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tb.uuid) FROM table_b tb) AS entry_count_b FROM table_a ta
```

Answer (score 2):

Count *0* is due to the implicit `CROSS JOIN` in `FROM table_a ta, table_b tb`, where one empty table cancels out the other one.

Joining is the wrong approach to begin with, as has been pointed out by other answers already. (Besides the side-effect at hand, building a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) gets *very* expensive for big tables. Run two separate counts instead.

Since `uuid` is the the PK in each table, use `count(*)`:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM table_a) AS count_a
     , (SELECT count(*) FROM table_b) AS count_b
;
```

`count(DISTINCT uuid)` would be a big waste, since `uuid` is `UNIQUE` by definition.

`count(uuid)` would still be wasteful, since that column is also `NOT NULL` by definition. Postgres has a [separate, faster implementation for `count(*)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html), simply counting rows.

About the misplaced join:

- [What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167201/what-does-from-x-y-mean-in-postgres/167217#167217)
- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

About the faster count(*):

- [Optimizing GROUP BY + COUNT DISTINCT on unnested jsonb column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63038210/optimizing-group-by-count-distinct-on-unnested-jsonb-column/63038532#63038532)
- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround I use for now:

```
SELECT a.count,
       b.count FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uuid) AS count FROM table_a) a,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uuid) AS count FROM table_b) b
```

Answer (score 0):

An other way to do it using `CROSS JOIN` :

```
with cte_table_a as (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uuid) AS entry_count_a FROM table_a
),
cte_table_b as (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uuid) AS entry_count_b FROM table_b
)
select * from cte_table_a
cross join cte_table_b
```

Or simply :

```
SELECT * 
from (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uuid) AS entry_count_a FROM table_a) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uuid) AS entry_count_b FROM table_b) b
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/9vRV4SS9)