# Rails: Allow only one record of a rails model to have a boolean property true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In the typical rails (4.2.x) blog app, I have a Post model. The post has a boolean column called primary. I want to enforce a model level constraint that at most one post has primary=true. If user sets a new post to be primary=true, all other posts must be marked primary=false before saving this post.

I could do this in the controller, when a post is created or updated to be primary=true, by changing all other posts to primary=false. Something like:

```
# in posts_controller#create and #update
...
if @post.primary
  [Post.all - self].select(&:primary).each do {|p|p.primary = false; p.save}
end
@post.save!
...
```

However, I want this to be a model level constraint, so I can add validations, unit tests, etc. that there is only one post with primary=true.
If I use a callback like before_commit, then I may run into an infinite loop since updating the older posts in a new post's before_commit will trigger the older posts' before_commit, etc.

How do I enforce this behavior at the model level?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ActiveRecord has some update attributes methods that don't trigger callbacks like `post.update_column`, `Post.update_all`, etc. So you can use these in a callback like

```
before_save :set_primary

private
def set_primary
  Post.where.not(id: id).update_all(primary: false)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

It might be worth considering a slightly different approach, where you instead use a singleton model -- say, Primaries -- which has a "post_id" that is set to the ID of the primary post. You could even make this a foreign key for extra elegance and automatic back-referencing to detect whether a given Post is primary or not.

(See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12463209/128977 for one approach to making an ActiveRecord singleton model.)

The advantages over coordinating a primary flag between all Post records are:

- **atomic updates** -- Using a "before_save" to update all other Posts to primary=false could in theory fail on the save action, leaving no primary=true record... or multiple saves at once could get dicey/racey, though I'm not certain how ActiveRecord handles threading here.
- **scalability** -- The number of Post records no longer matters when you use a single value to point to the primary post. Granted, your SQL backend should handle this pretty well, but updating 1-2 records is still faster than checking all of them.

---

Answer (score 2):

One approach you could use is to implement a custom validator on the model that prevents other primary Posts from being saved to the DB if one already exists.

You could then define a class method on Post to reset the primary Post to a normal Post and then set a different Post as the primary one.

**The Custom Validator** *(app/validators/primary_post_validator.rb)*

```
class PrimaryPostValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.primary
      record.errors[:primary] << "A Primary Post already exists!" if
        Post.where(primary: true).any?
    end
  end
end
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates_with PrimaryPostValidator

  def self.reset_primary!
    self.update_all(primary: false)
  end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  # any other columns you need go here.
  t.boolean  "primary",        default: false, null: false
  t.datetime "created_at",                      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                      null: false
end
```

This set up will allow you to control which Post gets assigned as the primary Post from a controller, and handle occasions where you need to swap the primary Post. I think it's a bad idea allowing the saving of a model to affect other records in the DB as you originally requested.

One way of handling this logic in the controller:

```
def make_primary
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  Post.reset_primary!
  @post.update_attributes(primary: true)
end
```

While this appears contrived compared to the accepted answer, I believe it gives you a much greater level of control over which Post gets set to primary and when. This solution will also work *with* validations, not skipping them like in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

1. Add a scoped unique index on `:primary` column.
2. Override `def primary=` to ignore falsey values, remove `primary` uniqueness validation (if any) from model.
3. Add a `before_save` callback that un-primaries any other records.

**Discussion**
It's 7 years after the ask, but none of the answers quite hit the mark, so here goes...

OP has two desired behaviours for the system:

> 1. Enforce a constraint that at most one post has `primary=true`.
> 2. If a new post is set to be `primary=true`, all other posts must be marked `primary=false`

There are three "layers" to consider:

1. Database-level data integrity - at most one post can be `primary=true`
2. Model-level validations (or maybe not!)
3. UI/UX level - maybe we can prevent invalid data reaching app to begin with.

A common misconception is that Rails ***validations*** ensure data integrity, but since there are `.update_all` and other validation-skipping mechanisms, they are unreliable at best.
Let's make sure the database itself only supports one primary! This is easy with [**scoped indexes**](https://coderwall.com/p/9hxejg/advanced-rails-indexing-where-clause-postgresql). Unfortunately, only Postgres supports them, not available for MySQL. YMMW.

In a DB migration

```
add_index(
  :posts,
  "primary",
  where: "(primary IS TRUE)",
  unique: true,
  name: :posts_uniq_primary_idx,
)
```

This will ensure data integrity. If we attempt to save another `primary`, we'll get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
   PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "posts_uniq_primary_idx"
```

*Normally*, we'd slap on a uniqueness validation and call it a day, but OP wants to support primary switching, and a validation would prevent that, so instead let's disable the ability to un-primary a record via normal means (`update_all` and friends can sidestep this, but we can't do anything about that).

```
def primary=(value)
  return unless value.present?
  
  super(value)
end
```

And make sure that creating or updating a record as the new `primary` makes all other records not primary:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :ensure_one_primary!

  private 

  def ensure_one_primary!
    return unless primary_changed?(to: true)

    Post.where(primary: true).where.not(id: id).update_all(primary: false)
  end
end
```

Bonus for UI - You'll likely be rendering `primary` as a radiobutton or a dropdown. Render the element as disabled for the record which already is `primary`, since a form submit of setting it to `false` wouldn't do anything anyway.

**Closing thoughts**

You probably don't want one primary Post in the whole table, likely it's scoped to some account. If so, the unique index would have to be not only on `"primary"` column alone, but a composite index on `"primary, account_id"`, and `ensure_one_primary!` callback would need to make sure to un-primary only posts belonging to new primary's account etc.