# Singleton resource: how to hide ID in routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, singleton

Although I'm working with Rails for 10 years now, the routing conventions and mechanisms still are something I don't really see through.

So I have created a singleton resource `AppConfig` where admins can maintain some global settings for my app:

[image: Screenshot of the admin area]

The `AppConfig` has one database field per setting, so it looks something like this:

[image: Screenshot of database tool]

As the app only needs one single `AppConfig` record, I've implemented some mechanism to retrieve it through `AppConfig.instance` (or create such a record when none is available), inspired by See [How to implement a singleton model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399447/how-to-implement-a-singleton-model):

```
def self.instance
  first_or_create! app_abbreviation: 'A4AA 2.0',
                   app_name: 'Access for All Audit 2.0',
                   app_slogan_de: 'Accessibility Audit Tool der nächsten Generation',
                   app_slogan_en: 'Next generation accessibility audit tool',
                   organisation_name_de: '«Zugang für alle»',
                   organisation_name_en: '«Access for all»',
                   organisation_abbreviation_de: 'ZFA',
                   organisation_abbreviation_en: 'A4A',
                   organisation_url: 'http://www.access-for-all.ch/'
end

def self.find(*args)
  instance
end
```

And I've added a route like this:

```
resources :app_configs, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
```

Everything works very well, but I'm bugged by the ID in the URL:

[image: Screenshot of browser URL]

Is there a way to hide it, and simply have `/en/app_configs` (pointing to `#show`) and `/en/app_configs/edit`? I fiddled around with `resource` (instead of `resources`) but I seem to have trouble getting it to work.

Comment: `resource` would be the best way probably, what doesn't seem to be working with that?

Comment: I second @Eyeslandic. `resource` is exactly what you are looking for. That or you can just define the routes your self e.g. `get 'app_configs', to: 'app_configs#show', as: :app_config; get 'app_configs/edit, to: 'app_configs#edit', as: edit_app_config; put 'app_configs', to: 'app_configs#update'`